# Cannot get proxy parameter working with lambda integration

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an api endpoint in API gateway defined as:

```
/guide/{proxy+}
```

which has get method and request paths defined as proxy.

Then I use lambda proxy which has and URL path parameters as:

```
proxy - method.request.path.proxy
```

I my lambda function I want to get the S3 file from a bucket based on that path, so I have:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();

    exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {  


    var bucketName = 'my-bucket';
    var keyName = 'guide/' + event.proxy;
    var fileContent;

    let data = await getS3File(bucketName, keyName)
    let response = {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": data.Body
};

callback(null, response);
};

async function getS3File(bucket, key) {
        const params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key
                       };

       return s3.getObject(params, (err) => {
         if (err) {
            // handle errors
            }
        }).promise();
}
```

Unfortunately, when I test this in test in api gateway, when I pass path as:
`en/guide.pdf` I get the following response:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "The specified key does not exist.",
  "errorType": "NoSuchKey",
}
```

The file is 100% there, when I test it within lambda (as a test), it gets downloaded. Why is so? Cannot figure it out.

NOTE: I do not want to select `Use Lambda Proxy integration` checkbox, because otherwise I loose some options then.

Comment: debug your event and see whether proxy is there or not, in most cases it comes under (event.pathParameters.proxy) pathParameters.